# Drawing image in canvas in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have a canvas element in HTML file which i am calling in an `<iframe>`. The problem is canvas loads some images while ignores others. Even some time the same image doesn't get drawn. I have tried multiple solutions. Path is of local filesystem. The image gets downloaded to the server first and then the script is called. Following is my JS script:

```
function loadCanvas(e) {
  alert(e.getSource().getProperty("sourcePath"));
  var path = e.getSource().getProperty("sourcePath");
  var source = e.getSource();
  alert('source' + source);
  var ADFiframe = source.findComponent("if1");
   alert('ADFiframe' + ADFiframe);
  var iframe = document.getElementById(ADFiframe.getClientId()).firstChild;
  alert('iframe' + iframe);
  var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
    alert('innerDoc' + innerDoc);
  var canvas = innerDoc.getElementById("imageView");
  alert('canvas' + canvas);
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = path;
  alert('path' +path);
  img.onload = function() {
    alert('img.src' + img.src);
  alert('Press OK to load your image');
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 700, 700);

  };
 // img.onerror= function(){
 // alert('Ooops,Error loading this image');
 // };
}
```

Comment: i am using InlineFrame just because of JSF(Oracle ADF) to load it on the view Layer.

Comment: i just tried it. It shows anomalous behavior.

Comment: For 1 thing, don't put an `alert` between `img.src` and `img.onload`, that alert delay may be just long enough to allow the img to load before it knows about it's `.onload` callback.

Comment: it doesn't work anyways...